# Android TableLayout issue with margins and layout_gravity

Tags: android, android-layout

It's easiest to just see what the problem is (skip down to image if you want to see that).

Here is my XML. It consists of four columns. The first row contains headers and the second row contains values.

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#0000FF"
            android:text="Start Day" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#0000FF"
            android:text="Start Time" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#0000FF"
            android:text="End Day" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#0000FF"
            android:text="End Time" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="REALLY LONG TEXT" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="REALLY LONG TEXT" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="REALLY LONG TEXT" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="REALLY LONG TEXT" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I would like the headers and values to always be centered. Just use wrap_content and layout_gravity=center, right? That works fine until I want to put a margin between the values (you can see this for the second row). Then, suddenly, everything goes awry.

This is what I get. What in the...?

[image]

The margins just screw up everything. I am surprised by this, as I would expect the margins to simply expand the width of each column, and the TableLayout to center the headers within this wider column. Instead...well, I'm not sure what's happening.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Unless you need your "values" cells' text to have a background, you could switch to padding instead of margins. You'll get the same look, and there's a decent chance that it'll work better. Off the cuff, it looks like the margins are not being taken into account in the cell width, but are being applied afterwards, which is why you're getting progressively slid further and further to the right.

Comment: Unfortunately the values cells actually do have a background. I'm just really confused by this because this didn't seem like an unusual situation. I swear I've done this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you give
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
for each textview,
after the first textview, it becomes 20 for subsequent ones.

And as suggested by CommonsWare, padding seems to solve your problem:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#0000FF"
            android:text="Start Day" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#0000FF"
            android:text="Start Time" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#0000FF"
            android:text="End Day" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#0000FF"
            android:text="End Time" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="REALLY LONG TEXT" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="REALLY LONG TEXT" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="REALLY LONG TEXT" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="REALLY LONG TEXT" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: I'm marking this as answered even though that won't really work for me. I can't use padding on the values TextViews, and I don't want to add an extra FrameLayout wrapping each one because there will be a lot of rows in the actual app.

Am I wrong, or is this unintuitive/wrong behavior? Shouldn't all column widths take into account all margins? If I increase the margins I can get columns drawn into other columns. There's no way this is useful behavior. Is there really no other way to get space between columns? Padding is of course not quite the same as margin.

Comment: If you increase the margins, "columns are drawn into other columns" happens only visually.  Otherwise afaik, the number of columns is the elements we add in a TableRow.
People try adding 'blank' columns for spacing. See if that works for you?  
Also, for a few implementations of tablelayout, please have a look at:  
http://mrbool.com/how-to-deal-with-table-layout-in-android/28008 , will be good if you can get something useful for your implementation

Comment: "If you increase the margins, "columns are drawn into other columns" happens only visually"

Well, yeah, but that's all that really matters, isn't it? :)

Comment: :) i mean programmatically if we keep that in mind then can work around with blank columns or some other way so visually the problem can be solved